# Do Excel UDFs update when you apply sort

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

As the question suggests, I'm seeing side effects (slowness) of the UDFs I've created when I apply a sort to my spreadsheet. I've created some UDFs in .NET and have deployed for testing. The function, behind the scenes, makes an API call then returns the data back to the cell. So I'm expecting some delay when I create the function to run initially. *BUT* I'm seeing some slowness in the application when I sort columns as if the UDFs are recalculating and calling the APIs. Is this normal behavior of the spreadsheet?

My function does have cell references and looks like the following:

```
=wsStateMiles("ALKCUR",G45,K45,1,J45,$G$2)
```

[image]

When I remove the function, the spreadsheet sorts very quickly, as the first thing I tried to deduce was actual slowness of Microsoft Excel.

(Additional info)

This has nothing to do with the sort, but when I add additional UDFs, it almost seems like Excel is running so slow it's recalculating the entire spreadsheet's UDFs again. Again, is this normal behavior of Excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sorting, unfortunately, this is the expected behavior.

When you sort a table, Excel dirties all the cells in the table. A UDF with any argument referencing a cell within the table will be recalculated.

For the case of adding additional UDFs, I'm not sure why it recalculates all the UDFs. A normal, non-volatile, VBA UDF will only cause the cell it's entered in to be calculated. Maybe your .NET UDFs are always volatile or there's a setting/attribute that's set to "volatile"? I know that [Managed-Code UDFs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/understanding-excel-services-udfs) have an attribute to turn volatility on/off.

Fortunately, there is some good news. Even though it's not possible to actually *stop* the UDFs from recalculating, it is possible speed them up.

It requires a static array in the UDF to store the current state of all the return values (i.e. the "Miles" column, `L:L`, in your example), and a "Suspend" cell used as a argument to the UDF. Before sorting, set the Suspend cell to `TRUE`, and afterwards back to `FALSE`.

When suspended, the UDF will return the result corresponding to its caller cell from the stored values. When restarted, it will perform as normal, but also update the stored value.

The trick to get this working is to also implement hysteresis. The first call 
to the UDF per cell *after* restarting, must also returned the stored value.

Alternatively, instead of using a "Suspend" cell, by storing all the passed arguments in the static array as well, the UDF could always return the stored value unless the arguments change. Once they do change, the API would be called and the result stored before being returned.

This second technique would also automatically speed up the recalculation when adding additional UDFs. (The first technique could also be used when adding UDFs by "suspending" before adding them and "resuming" afterwards.)

Comment: Thanks for providing some techniques to try. After I realized the sorting might be crippling my spreadsheet, I started looking into caching and what might be close to your alternate suggested technique. Also another +1 for reminding me to check if my UDFs are volatile. I looked and it doesn't appear that flag had been set (its default is false). But I am looking at that documentation on the link you sent more thoroughly now. So again thanks.

Comment: @FusRoDah I had another thought. If it's too hard to do the caching in your .NET UDFs, it is a really simple matter to write a wrapper UDF in VBA and do the caching there.